# How to reopen a changeset after a commit revert?

Tags: git, gerrit

I reverted a commit in Gerrit to fix a defect. How can I push the fix to the closed changeset?

```
Steps: 
1. I pushed my code to Gerrit.
2. I merged the code.
3. I reverted the changeset
4. I want to Push the code to the closed changeset using the same change-id
```

Gerrit doesn't allow pushing code to a closed changeset, it gives [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (change xxx closed).

Also, after reverting a commit, Gerrit creates a new change ID, but this revert also gets merged and I can't push anything to it.

Comment: You can't. A submitted change cannot be reopened again. Commit the fix with a new change ID and push the new commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can't push a commit to a closed change.

You need to amend the commit, replace the Change-Id, and push the commit to a new change.

You also can use the "REVERT" button in the change screen on the Gerrit UI to easily execute the revert task.